# I want to be able to post a video to Facebook the way that Boomerang does it

Tags: swift, url, video, sharing, fbsdk

The Facebook SDK docs shows that you can use a URL for imagePickerController to share a video from your app to Facebook:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

However, I'd like to be able to share a video to Facebook from my app without going into an image picker. Boomerang does just that by first saving the video to the user's camera roll, and then displaying a dialog to share the video. It looks to be a perquisite to save the video first and get that URL to be able to share a video to Facebook, unlike photos.

I can save the video to my photo library just fine, but I can't get my app to switch to Facebook to preview the share dialog. Two "TIC Read Status" messages appear in my console, but there are no errors.

To be more clear on what I'm doing, I save the video to my library, and upon completion, I sort my camera roll's media to descending order by creation date, and fetch the first object. I then convert that asset to a URL that should be able to be used by FBSDKShareVideo.

My URL looks like "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/129APPLE/IMG_9515.MP4"

```
CustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.save(URL: self.fileURL, completion: {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print(self.fileURL)
        self.enableButtons(enabled:true)
        self.activityTextStatus?.remove()
        self.timedLabel.setLabel("Video saved.", view:self.view)
    })

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.fileURL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject

            PHImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult!, options: nil, resultHandler: { (avurlAsset, audioMix, dict) in
                let newObj = avurlAsset as! AVURLAsset

                let videoURL:URL = newObj.url

                print(videoURL)

                let photo = self.uiImages[0]

                let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
                sharePhoto.image = photo

                let filePath = self.fileURL

                // get size of video in bytes
                do {
                    var fileSize : UInt64
                    let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: (filePath?.path)!)
                    fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64

                    print(fileSize)

                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }

                let shareVideo : FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo(videoURL: videoURL, previewPhoto: sharePhoto)

                let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
                content.video = shareVideo

                let shareDialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()

                shareDialog.shareContent = content

                shareDialog.mode = .native
                shareDialog.show()

            })

        }
    }

})
```

Comment: It looks like even the developers over at Facebook don't have answers for me. The API's status has been "degraded performance" with barely any activity, so I'm guessing they are dropping the API altogether and starting something new. No wonder most of the documentation is still in Objective-C!

Comment: How did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I just used a regular UIActivityViewController. UIActivityViewController can share media with any app that supports it, so it shows a list of where you can share. Much easier than hassling with the API, although I heard they either were working on, or put out a new one. Other than that, look up how to use UIActivityViewController with Swift for more details.